# Call method of Future not being called

Tags: java, executorservice, futuretask

I have this piece of code:

```
final Future<Map<String, Object>> handle = FrameworkUtil.getExecutorService("GENERAL").submit(
                new Callable<Map<String, Object>>() {

                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    @Override
                    public Map<String, Object> call() throws SSPolicyException {
                        LOG.debug("calling SSPolicyEvaluator.getPolicyDecision()");
                        Map<String, Object> policyDecision = policyModule.getPolicyDecision(ssoTokenStr, "*", actions, env);
                        LOG.debug("SSPolicyEvaluator.getPolicyDecision() returned successfully");
                        return policyDecision;
                    }
                });
```

Most of the times it works fine but every now or then, call to method `call` is not executed (even log lines are not printed.) and I get timeout on calling

`handle.get(TIME_OUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`

Checked thread dump but no threads are stuck and pool is not fully utilized.

What could be the other reasons of `call` not getting executed.

Comment: What's the exact class of the `ExecutorService` returned? Can it vary from one call of `getExecutorService()` to another? Can it sometimes return an ExecutorService that uses some very strange scheduling scheme?